# Cross-platform MIDI player for Python

Tags: python, midi

Is there any MIDI library for Python that works cross-platform, at least in Windows and the latest Mac OS? I've been using PyGame, but it doesn't work with the latest Mac OS anymore.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think [`rtmidi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-rtmidi) may serve your purpose, they are Python bindings to the C++ RtMidi, which is a cross-platform API for realtime MIDI in/out.